# How to prevent progurad from keeping singleton classes names

Tags: java, android, singleton, proguard, android-proguard

I use proguard on android and I noticed that it keeps my singleton classes names.
Can anyone tell me why or how can I tell it to obfuscate them?

My proguard-project.txt:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable { *; }


## check why we need this
#-keep public class * {
#    public protected *;
#}


# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Output code example (I would like to obfuscate "WebHelper"):

```
public class WebHelper {
    protected static WebHelper b = null;
    private static Handler j;
    public Context a;
    private hw c;
    private int d = 10;
    private int e = 0;
    private int f = 45000;
    private byte[] g;
    private boolean h = false;
    private boolean i = false;

    public class DebugModeException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2841735008657022909L;

        public DebugModeException() {
            super("Server is in debug mode");
        }
    }

    protected byte[] a() {
        if (this.g == null) {
            this.g = new byte[32768];
        }
        return this.g;
    }

    public synchronized void a(Runnable runnable) {
        j.post(runnable);
    }

    public hw b() {
        if (this.c == null) {
            this.c = new id().a();
        }
        return new hw();
    }

    protected WebHelper(Context context) {
        this.a = context;
        j = new Handler();
        c();
    }

    public void c() {
        if (ResponseCache.getDefault() == null) {
            File file = new File(this.a.getCacheDir(), "http");
            try {
                Class.forName("android.net.http.HttpResponseCache").getMethod("install", new Class[]{File.class, Long.TYPE}).invoke(null, new Object[]{file, Long.valueOf(5242880)});
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ResponseCache.setDefault(new uo());
            }
        }
    }

    public static WebHelper d() {
        return b;
    }

    public static WebHelper a(Context context) {
        b = new WebHelper(context);
        return b;
    }

    public void a(ur urVar, URL url) {
        us usVar;
        String a;
        Throwable e;
        InputStream errorStream;
        Throwable th;
        if (e()) {
            if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            }
            if (this.h) {
                usVar = new us(this, "Get  " + url);
            } else {
                usVar = null;
            }
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            try {
                a = a(new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                if (urVar != null) {
                    try {
                        urVar.a = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e = e2;
                        try {
                            vb.a("WebHelper", "stringFromUrlGet Failed, trying to get error stream", e);
                            errorStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
                            if (urVar != null) {
                                urVar.b = a(errorStream);
                                urVar.a = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e3) {
                            vb.a("WebHelper", "stringFromUrlGet->urlConnection.getErrorStream Failed", e);
                            urVar.b = e3.getMessage();
                        } catch (Throwable th2) {
                            e = th2;
                            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                            if (usVar != null) {
                                usVar.a();
                            }
                            urVar.c = a;
                            throw e;
                        }
                        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                        if (usVar != null) {
                            usVar.a();
                        }
                        urVar.c = a;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                if (usVar != null) {
                    usVar.a();
                }
                urVar.c = a;
                return;
            } catch (Throwable e4) {
                th = e4;
                a = null;
                e = th;
                vb.a("WebHelper", "stringFromUrlGet Failed, trying to get error stream", e);
                errorStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
                if (urVar != null) {
                    urVar.b = a(errorStream);
                    urVar.a = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                if (usVar != null) {
                    usVar.a();
                }
                urVar.c = a;
                return;
            } catch (Throwable e42) {
                th = e42;
                a = null;
                e = th;
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                if (usVar != null) {
                    usVar.a();
                }
                urVar.c = a;
                throw e;
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Network is not available");
    }

    public void a(ur urVar, String str) {
        if (str != null && str.toString().length() >= 8) {
            a(urVar, new URL(str));
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean a(String str, File file) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        OutputStream fileOutputStream;
        MalformedURLException e;
        IOException e2;
        Exception e3;
        Throwable th;
        Object obj;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        boolean z = false;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!(str == null || file == null)) {
                try {
                    URLConnection openConnection = new URL(str).openConnection();
                    openConnection.setUseCaches(true);
                    openConnection.connect();
                    inputStream = openConnection.getInputStream();
                    try {
                        byte[] a = a();
                        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                int read = inputStream.read(a, 0, a.length);
                                if (read < 0) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                fileOutputStream.write(a, 0, read);
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e4) {
                                e = e4;
                                outputStream = inputStream;
                            } catch (IOException e5) {
                                e2 = e5;
                                outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                            } catch (Exception e6) {
                                e3 = e6;
                                outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                            } catch (Throwable th2) {
                                th = th2;
                                outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                            }
                        }
                        outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                        z = true;
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e7) {
                        e = e7;
                        fileOutputStream = null;
                        Object obj2 = inputStream;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        obj = outputStream;
                        outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            try {
                                inputStream.close();
                            } catch (Throwable th3) {
                                th3.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            try {
                                outputStream.flush();
                                outputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e22) {
                                e22.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return z;
                    } catch (IOException e8) {
                        e22 = e8;
                        e22.printStackTrace();
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                        return z;
                    } catch (Exception e9) {
                        e3 = e9;
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                        return z;
                    } catch (Throwable th4) {
                        th3 = th4;
                        th3.printStackTrace();
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                        return z;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e10) {
                    e = e10;
                    fileOutputStream = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    obj = outputStream;
                    outputStream = fileOutputStream;
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    return z;
                } catch (IOException e11) {
                    e22 = e11;
                    inputStream = null;
                    e22.printStackTrace();
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    return z;
                } catch (Exception e12) {
                    e3 = e12;
                    inputStream = null;
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    return z;
                } catch (Throwable th5) {
                    th3 = th5;
                    inputStream = null;
                    th3.printStackTrace();
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    return z;
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return z;
    }

    public boolean e() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.a.getSystemService("connectivity");
        if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String a(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) {
            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (readLine == null) {
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            stringBuilder.append(readLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you have disabled or removed following lines as it may cause your class to prevent from renaming,

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

though you have kept those lines commented in Proguard file you have posted here, just verify if it is not enabled.

And also if your Proguard has `'-keepclasseswithmembers'` wihch keeps the class name, and any class with a static field will not change its name. change it to `'-keepclassmembers'` will obfuscate the class names. 
hope it helps!